# Why is OrderedDict() ~10x slower than dict() and list()?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Just run the tests below and noticed that filling an `OrderedDict()` is roughly an order of magnitude slower than filling a `dict()` or a `list()`.

Why?

```
# list()
In [1]: timeit test_list()
1000 loops, best of 3: 298 us per loop

# dict()    
In [3]: timeit test_dict()
1000 loops, best of 3: 269 us per loop

# dict()    
In [3]: timeit test_ord_dict()                                                  
100 loops, best of 3: 1.77 ms per loop
```

with:

```
def test_ord_dict():
  a = OrderedDict()
  for el in xrange(1000):
    a[el] = np.random.randint(100)
  return a

def test_dict():
  a = dict()
  for el in xrange(1000):
    a[el] = np.random.randint(100)
  return a

def test_list():
  a = list()
  for el in xrange(1000):
    a.append(np.random.randint(100))
  return a
```

Comment: In case anyone finds this question and just wants to have a **dict that preserves insertion order** - you no longer have to use OrderedDict. Since Python 3.7 the language now requires dicts to preserve insertion order `https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html`.

Comment: Thanks @user136036 True. Time flies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OrderedDict` is implemented in pure Python, so here's the relevant part of the source:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value, dict_setitem=dict.__setitem__):
    'od.__setitem__(i, y) <==> od[i]=y'
    # Setting a new item creates a new link at the end of the linked list,
    # and the inherited dictionary is updated with the new key/value pair.
    if key not in self:
        root = self.__root
        last = root[0]
        last[1] = root[0] = self.__map[key] = [last, root, key]
    return dict_setitem(self, key, value)
```

If the key doesn't exist, you'll be creating a new list and accessing two items from a list, which will slow things down.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus A lot of non-essential types have a C implementation *too*, such as `deque` and `defaultdict` (to stay within `collections`).

Comment: The speed difference changed in python3, now OrderedDict is just a little slower

Answer (score 5):

Two reasons:

1. An `OrderedDict`, by definition, has to do more work than a `dict`.
2. (much more importantly) `OrderedDict` is [written in Python](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8de172ff15b3/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l18), while [`dict`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8de172ff15b3/Objects/dictobject.c) and [`list`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8de172ff15b3/Objects/listobject.c) are written in C.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the first. It certainly provides an additional guarantee, but an implementation completely geared towards those guarantees shouldn't result in significant additional work (see also: a python-dev or python-ideas thread a few months ago about a change to dict that would automatically preserve order in many cases and make it easier to maintain in others). Certainly not enough to be an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: @delnan I agree that #2 is much more significant than #1. I haven't studied the code for `OrderedDict`, but wouldn't be surprised if it's more careful to be as close to `dict` as possible in behaviour than it is to be performant; that would be the typical approach in Python, at least.